# Mupdf in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-ndk, mupdf

I'm trying to integrate Mupdf to Android. The documentation in their site seem to be out-dated. I got the latest master from git. I saw two ways by which .so files can be build in Developer site:

1. CmakeLists.txt
2. adding Android.mk file

First method is creating the Lib directory with it's sub-directories but no .so file is created.
Second method is giving an error.
Can someone tell me how this is done.
Below shown is the error i got when i added Android.mk file.
[image]

Comment: Where are you looking? I don't believe any developer documentation for mupdf mentions cmakelists.txt. What error do you get when trying the Android.mk?

Comment: @JosephH I have put the error image in question. please check it